# Retrive the Data in to Dropdown list Using foreign key id

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, regex

in my database there have two tables "stok" and "stock_avail" 
in "stok" there have two column "pid" and "name" also in "stock_avail" table have four column "id" "quantity" "productname" 
"pid". here "pid" is a foreign key of stok. When i insert the "name" of "stok" that will automatically retrieve the "quantity" in
 to the textbox. I need to retrieve "productname"  using pid of "stok" when i enter the name,also i need it get into the dropdown list.
 example-when i enter the name like pen i need to show in the blupen,redpen,etc..in dropdown list.

here is my addsell.php file

```html
<?php include_once("init.php");
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/auto/css/jquery.autocomplete.css">
 <?php include_once("tpl/common_js.php"); ?>  
        <script src="lib/auto/js/jquery.autocomplete.js "></script>  
  
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    
     $("#item").autocomplete("stock.php", {
  width: 160,
  autoFill: true,
  mustMatch: true,
  selectFirst: true
 });
        
        $("#item").blur(function()
   {    
    $.post('check_item_details.php', {stock_name1: $(this).val() },
    function(data){
                                
      $("#stock").val(data.stock);
   if(data.sell!=undefined)
   $("#0").focus();
        
   }, 'json');
   });
        
 $('#test1').jdPicker();
 $('#test2').jdPicker();
  
  var hauteur=0;
  $('.code').each(function(){
   if($(this).height()>hauteur) hauteur = $(this).height();
  });

  $('.code').each(function(){ $(this).height(hauteur); });
 });
 </script>

</head>
<body>
      <?php
 //Gump is libarary for Validatoin
 if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
        $data=$_GET['msg'];
        $msg='<p style=color:#153450;font-family:gfont-family:Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif>'.$data.'</p>';//
      ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 jAlert('<?php echo  $msg; ?>', 'POSNIC');
 </script>
                                    <?php
                                        }
                                     ?>
    
   <form name="form1" method="post" id="form1" action="">
                    <table class="form" >
                      <tr>
                       <td>Item:</td>
    <!-- <td>product select</td> -->
                          <td>Available Stock:</td>     
                      </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input name="item"  type="text" id="item"  maxlength="200"  class="round default-width-input " style="width: 150px"   /></td>
                        <!-- need here to add drop downlist -->               
                        <td><input name="stock"  type="text" id="stock" readonly maxlength="200"  class="round  my_with"   /></td>
                       </tr>
                  </table>
             
                </form>
   
</body>
</html>
```

and also here is the check_item_details.php file

```html
<?php
include_once("init.php");

$stock_id =$line->stock_id; 
$line = $db->queryUniqueObject("SELECT * FROM stock_avail  WHERE name ='".$_POST['stock_name1']."'");
$stock=$line->quantity;
if($line!=NULL)
{
$arr = array ("stock"=>"$stock");
echo json_encode($arr);

}
else
{
$arr1 = array ("no"=>"no");
echo json_encode($arr1);

}
?>
```

also my stock.php file

```html
<?php
include_once("init.php");
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;
$db->query("SELECT * FROM stok ");
  while ($line = $db->fetchNextObject()) {
   if (strpos(strtolower($line->name), $q) !== false) {
  echo "$line->name\n";
 }
 }

?>
```

Comment: One does not "retrieve via a Foreign key", one might use an "index" for efficiency.  I can't see either without `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; please provide such.

Comment: Is PHP going to populate the dropdown?  Or is Javascript going to use AJAX to get the data and then do the populating?